# Confused about reference and namespace

Tags: c#

I have created a new class library(DLL) and when I'm trying to create an object of a class from the DLL in another assembly or library, then it's not working and I guess there has to be about the namespace or a reference problem, perhaps both becuase there are different namespaces.

Should I be the other library namespace like using namespace in the beginning of the the other library classes to be able to create an object of this class inside the DLL?

I tested to right click on the on of the other librarys and choose Add reference to this new DLL, but this didn't work. Some help is preciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "this didn't work"? 
we need more details.

Comment: With this I mean I couldn't make an object, VS didn't help med when I was writing the class name, I guess thats because it not knowing it!?

Comment: Yes. I think it helped with the namespace

Comment: That has nothing to do with the namespace - separate issue.

Comment: Why not? When I removed the using and the namespace of the DLL I got the red line below the code again!? So for me it seems it has to do about this and perhaps something else as well

Comment: @3D-kreativ it's a separate issue because type accessibility (is it public?) is not directly related to the compiler's type resolution algorithm (is a `using` directive is in force). Compilation can fail because the compiler cannot resolve the type, or because it resolves the type and finds that it is inaccessible. In other words, there are two independent conditions that must be satisfied. You can fail to get somewhere on a bus because the bus never arrives, or because you have no ticket. Saying "it helped with the namespace" is like saying "the bus arrived; it helped with the bus ticket."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the references and then access it like follows:

```
 using MyLibrary
```

That should be all you need.

Then you would acess the methods as follows:

```
 var result = new MyLibrary.MyMethod()
```

Comment: Sorry that was just me making up a name. Hang on i will change it!

Comment: It seems like it's working now when I typed using and then the namespace of the class in the DLL. And If I got it right, I also has to right click on all other librarys and assemlies and add reference to the new DLL if there is a need to use it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You only need to add the reference in projects where you are going to use it. If you arent using it then you dont need to add it.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be the other library namespace like using namespace in the beginning of the the other library classes to be able to create an object of this class inside the DLL?

Yes, provided you add a reference to that assembly (DLL), and that the types in your library are *public*.

> I tested to right click on the on of the other librarys and choose Add reference to this new DLL, but this didn't work. Some help is preciated.

This is absolutely required in order to use the types defined within your library.  The reference is what allows the compiler to find and use the types.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are incorrect to say that you must use `using`.  You do not *need* to use `using` statements at all.  References, on the other hand, are required.

For example, assume you have created an assembly called `TwentyNine.dll`, including this type declaration:

```
namespace Kreativ.Application.One
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static int GetSomeResult()
        {
            return 863;
        }
    }
 }
```

Now, you're making a new application, and you want to call GetSomeResult().  *You must add a reference to TwentyNine.dll in your new project.*

Most commonly, you'd call the method this way:

```
using Kreativ.Application.One;
using System;

namespace Kreativ.Application.Two
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int i = SomeClass.GetSomeResult();
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But you can do this without using `using`:

```
namespace Kreativ.Application.Two
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int i = Kreativ.Application.One.SomeClass.GetSomeResult();
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add the reference, and then in whatever file you are using it in, you need to add the `using` directive at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

- first you need to add a reference to a libarary (I supos lie you did)

but it's not enough

- you need to decalre a namespace of the *type* you use (there could be more then one namepsace in your library) or on top of the file

  using MyLibraryNameSpace;

or in code-line, like

```
MyLibraryNameSpace.MyLibType t = new MyLibraryNameSpace.MyLibType();
```